# Image not loading on Map using MapIcon

Tags: c#, geolocation, win-universal-app

the problem i am facing is that when i put an **image** for a **mapicon**, it feels like the mapicon got deleted from the map.

```
BasicGeoposition bg = new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 33.98151688, Longitude = 35.63329697 };
        Geopoint snPoint = new Geopoint(bg);
        MapIcon mapIcon1 = new MapIcon();
        mapIcon1.Location = snPoint;
        mapIcon1.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx://Assets/MapPin.png"));
        mapIcon1.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0);
        MyMap.MapElements.Add(mapIcon1);
```

If i remove mapIcon1.Image, it shows a default pin point.

[Without mapIcon1.Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBILu.jpg)

[With mapIcon1.Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2bOZ.jpg)

I am using VS 2015, UWP project.

Comment: I have tested your code, it works.  In code `mapIcon1.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/MapPin.png"));` you miss a '/'. Please try for this. If there has any problem, please tell me.

Comment: If you can please write it as an answer,and explain why it works. Just so i assign it as the answer. Thanks for your assistance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri` creates a random access stream around the specified URI. And the valid URI schemes are http, https, ms-appx, and ms-appdata.

> Use the ms-appx schemes to refer to app files that come from the app's package ([see App packages and deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464929.aspx)). Such files are typically static images, data, code, and layout files.

The URI authority for the ms-appx scheme is the package identity name that is defined in the package manifest. It is therefore limited in URI form to the set of characters allowed in a package identity name. The package name is limited to those in the current running app's package dependency graph.

For example:

```
Package package = Package.Current;
PackageId packageId = package.Id;
String output = packageId.Name;
string str = string.Format("ms-appx://{0}/Assets/Map-512.png", output);
mapIcon1.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri(str));
```

The value for the authority, when the given authority is blank, is the currently running app's package.

For example:

```
mapIcon1.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Map-512.png"));
```

More info, see [URI schemes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj655406.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
BasicGeoposition geoPosition = new BasicGeoposition();
geoPosition.Latitude = 27.175015;
geoPosition.Longitude = 78.042155;
// get position
Geopoint myPoint = new Geopoint(geoPosition);
//create POI
MapIcon myPOI = new MapIcon { Location = myPoint, Title = "My Position", NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0), ZIndex = 0 };
// Display an image of a MapIcon
myPOI.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/pin.png"));
// add to map and center it
MyMap.MapElements.Add(myPOI);
MyMap.Center = myPoint;
MyMap.ZoomLevel = 10;

MapScene mapScene = MapScene.CreateFromLocationAndRadius(new Geopoint(geoPosition), 500, 150, 70);
await MyMap.TrySetSceneAsync(mapScene);
```

Check [**This VIDEO**](https://youtu.be/xJveKt99MXY)

[image: Map control]